# dropbox authentication using angular promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a code for dropbox authentication using promises in Angular. I have a service by the name of dropboxAuthServ which returns a promise object containing the instance of the dropbox client that was created.

In my controller, I am trying to use this promise object to display some text on the view. I also plan to chain promises later on, so that I can use this dropboxClient that i created in another service that I am writing.

The problem is its just not working. I am new to Angular and modularized programming in javascript. So my understanding might be flawed. Please do feel free to share your opinions. I am attaching the code below.

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'dropBoxAuthServ',
    function ($scope, dropBoxAuthServ) {
        dropBoxAuthServ
            .getDbClient()
        .then(function(result){
            alert('Success' + result);
        });
    //$scope.result = dropBoxAuthServ.result;

}]);
```

**Service**

```
var myApp = angular.module('quickPlansApp',[]);

myApp.factory('dropBoxAuthServ', function($q){
    var
      dropboxClientCredentials,
      //dropboxAuthDriver,
      dropboxClient;

    // Insert your Dropbox app key here:
    var DROPBOX_APP_KEY = '';

    dropboxClientCredentials = {
      key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    dropboxClient = new Dropbox.Client(dropboxClientCredentials);
    return{
        getDbClient: function(){
               var defer = $q.defer;
               dropboxClient.authenticate(function (error, client) {
                   if (error) {
                     throw error;
                   }
                   $timeout(function(){
                    defer.resolve({
                    'DBClient': client
               })},1000);
                });
            return defer.promise;
         }
      };
});
```

Comment: Why are you using the timeout? You aren't injecting the $timeout so it should be erroring out when you try to use it. Aside from that, console.log your client and see what comes back. Alerts don't show you anything discernable.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but you need to invoke the $q.defer function instead of referencing it: var defer = $q.defer();

Comment: @adrichman ... Am using $timeout as it was mentioned as a way to implement asynchronous calls. I tried injecting $timeout and even tried removing it. The console.log(client) is not returning anything. Is there any fundamental issues with my approach?

Comment: @tasseKATT... Thanks for pointing it out ..But that was a typo

Comment: @meajmal fundamental - not sure. But the callback won't be run until the remote API responds, so the won't help. Are you checking result['DBClient'] anywhere?

Comment: @adrichman... I tried to do a console log of dbclient ... but no success ... If i write the authenticate code in the controller it is working fine ... but when i try to wrap it as a service and return a promise object, there is nothing happening ..seriously stumped